# sqlite is fully qualifying field names in views

Tags: sqlite, sql-view

I cannot find how to disable full qualification of field names in SQLite when querying through a view. (Don't laugh at `mtcars`, table naming is a symptom from other testing ...)

The setup:

```
sqlite> create table mtcars (id int, mpg real, cyl int, vs int);
sqlite> insert into mtcars values (1, 21.0, 6, 0);
sqlite> insert into mtcars values (2, 22.8, 4, 1);
sqlite> insert into mtcars values (1, 21.4, 6, 1);
sqlite> .headers on
```

"Normal" table access, no views:

```
sqlite> select * from mtcars foo;
id|mpg|cyl|vs
1|21.0|6|0
2|22.8|4|1
1|21.4|6|1
sqlite> select foo.* from mtcars foo;
id|mpg|cyl|vs
1|21.0|6|0
2|22.8|4|1
1|21.4|6|1
sqlite> select foo.mpg,foo.cyl from mtcars foo;
mpg|cyl
21.0|6
22.8|4
21.4|6
```

All normal so far. Create and use a view:

```
sqlite> create view vwmtcars as select mpg,cyl from mtcars;
sqlite> select * from vwmtcars foo;
mpg|cyl
21.0|6
22.8|4
21.4|6
sqlite> select foo.* from vwmtcars foo;
mpg|cyl
21.0|6
22.8|4
21.4|6
```

Still normal. However:

```
sqlite> select foo.mpg,foo.cyl from vwmtcars foo;
foo.mpg|foo.cyl
21.0|6
22.8|4
21.4|6
```

I was expecting `mpg|cyl`, not `foo.mpg|foo.cyl`.

Two questions:

1. Why are the field names being full-qualified?
2. Can I disable this?

(Win10 x64, sqlite3 3.14.2 (as included in Git-for-Windows 2.11.1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is just to reset the column names with aliases:

```
select f.mpg as mpg,f.cyl as cyl from vwmtcars f;
mpg|cyl
21.0|6
22.8|4
21.4|6
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly one workaround I had in mind. I'm drafting an answer, as I found the "reason why" if not a more robust workaround. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Seems like this behavior is in flux: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Aliasing-and-columns-names-td14489.html

Comment: "In flux" from 2008, slow discourse :-)  I saw some other discussions like that, and it appears that I am seeing similar behavior. Perhaps I'm just reaffirming a "best practice" of always being explicit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Further explained, for future reference.

Two of [SQLite's Pragmas](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) are relevant: `short_column_names` (currently set to `1`) and `full_column_names` (currently `0`). Both are deprecated.

According to the logic used for naming the returned columns (paraphrased, full text in the pragma link above):

1. If there is an `AS` clause, use it.
2. If it's an expression, use it.
3. If `short_column_names` is true, use just the column name.
4. If both `*_column_names` are false, rule 2 applies.
5. Use `TABLE.COLUMN`

Facts for this installation:

- `pragma compile_options` does not list `OMIT_DEPRECATED`, so the two pragmas are usable and valid (albeit discouraged);
- `short_column_names` is true, `full_column_names` is false (I changed neither);

From this, I'm inferring that SQLite is treating the aliased VIEW and column names as an *expression*, therefore being resolved in case 2 and never checking for the pragmas in case 3 or beyond.

The solution I'm leaning towards (as @gregory just answered) is to explicitly name each variable (`select foo.mpg as mpg, foo.cyl as cyl ...`). And though this seems like fixing the symptom and not the underlying flaw in logic, it is consistent with one (of many) Best Practices in SQL code: **always be explicit**.